# Getting length of list present in state not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list present in state of my react app:

```
constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            topText: "",
            bottomText: "",
            randomImage: "http://i.imgflip.com/1bij.jpg",
            allMemeImgs: []
        }
        
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }
```

I am using an API which gets all the image URLs and stores it in `allMemeImgs`:

```
componentDidMount() {
        fetch("https://api.imgflip.com/get_memes")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
            var { data: {memes: a}} = json
            this.setState({allMemeImgs: a})
        })
    }
```

in the `render()` method I am able to log the length of `allMemeImgs`:

```
console.log(this.state.allMemeImgs.length)
```

Output:

> 100

I also have a button which uses random class to generate a random index from the `allMemeImgs` and sets the variable `randomImage` from state to a random URL:

```
<button className="meme-form-button" onClick={this.handleClick}>Gen</button>
```

`handleClick()`:

```
handleClick() {
        var index = Math.random() * this.state.allMemeImgs.length
        console.log(this.state.allMemeImgs.length)
}
```

I am not able to access the length of `allMemeImgs` in this method.

I am able to access the length of `allMemeImgs` in `render()` method but not in `handleClick()` method

This is my whole code:

```
import React from "react"

class MemeGenerator extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            topText: "",
            bottomText: "",
            randomImage: "http://i.imgflip.com/1bij.jpg",
            allMemeImgs: []
        }
        
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("https://api.imgflip.com/get_memes")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
            var { data: {memes: a}} = json
            this.setState({allMemeImgs: a})
        })
    }
    
    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState(prevState => {
            return {
                [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
                [event.target.name]: event.target.value
            }
        })
    }
    
    handleClick() {
        var index = Math.random() * this.state.allMemeImgs.length
        console.log(this.state.allMemeImgs.length)//not able to access, getting unknown error in scrimba
    }
    
    render() {
        console.log(this.state.allMemeImgs.length)//able to access here
        return (
            <div>
                <form className="meme-form">
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        name="topText"
                        value={this.state.topText} 
                        placeholder="Top text"
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        name="bottomText" 
                        value={this.state.bottomText} 
                        placeholder="Bottom text"
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                    <br />
                    <button className="meme-form-button" onClick={this.handleClick}>Gen</button>
                </form>
                <div className="meme">
                    <img className="meme-image" src={this.state.randomImage} alt="meme" />
                    <h2 className="top">{this.state.topText.toUpperCase()}</h2>
                    <h2 className="bottom">{this.state.bottomText.toUpperCase()}</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default MemeGenerator
```

Kindly comment if more information is needed

**EDIT**

It worked after I added this line to the `constructor()`:

```
this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
```

Whenever we are accessing the `state` from any method we have to bind it.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, to avoid binding (or forget it), is using [class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields):

```
handleClick = () => {
        var index = Math.random() * this.state.allMemeImgs.length
        console.log(this.state.allMemeImgs.length) }
```